# The imported Shared library is not referring to the plugin

Tags: 14.04, shared-library, python-2.7

I have created a test.so file with a library linked with that (DijSDK.h)

The Flow is

test.so uses ---- DijSDK.h Which inturn calls ---- libsynthcam.so(plugin)file

Now I am importing that .so file in my python command prompt. Which is failing to link with libsynthcam library.

DijSDK.h will call this libsynthcam.so during runtime. DijSDK.h searches the current working directory for libsynthcam.so file.

I am importing the test.so file from the terminal - python editor. How to know the current working directory of this test.so file?

I tried placing the libsynthcam.so file in the following places

/usr/lib

/usr/local/lib

/usr/lib/i386-linu-gnu

/usr/local/lib/i386-linu-gnu

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

But still it is failing. I am new to Ubuntu with Python usage,Hoping for a good response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placed the camera libraries under /usr/bin/ where the python.exe exists and it worked.